# Using bools in calculations to avoid branches

Tags: c++, optimization, c++11, boolean, micro-optimization

Here's a little micro-optimization curiosity that I came up with:

```
struct Timer {
    bool running{false};
    int ticks{0};

    void step_versionOne(int mStepSize) {
        if(running) ticks += mStepSize;
    }

    void step_versionTwo(int mStepSize) {
        ticks += mStepSize * static_cast<int>(running);
    }
};
```

It seems the two methods practically do the same thing. Does the second version avoid a branch (and consequently, is faster than the first version), or is any compiler able to do this kind of optimization with `-O3`?

Comment: Is it specified that ``true`` must be 1 or can it be any non-zero value?

Comment: @JonasWielicki: per the standard (§4.5 Integer promotions), `true` promotes to one and `false` to zero. Other values are not permitted for `bool`.

Comment: Surprisingly, GCC doesn't perform this optimization. It generates compare and branch instructions or a multiplication instruction, respectively. (Note that you don't need the `static_cast`, `bool` promotes to `int` in arithmetic expressions.)

Comment: @larsmans: Yep, that's surprising. What version of GCC? Did you use `-O3`? I will test it on my own toolkit as soon as I can.

Comment: Note that using multiplication doesn't have to be faster then branching, especially if branch is predictable. There is also `ticks += mStepSize & -static_cast<int>(running)` on 2-complement, which *might* be faster than those.

Comment: @VittorioRomeo GCC 4.7, with `-O3`.

Comment: Scraping the paint of your car might reduce its weight and let you go faster. Oh no, maybe the paint actually reduces air resistance. In other words: don't play these micro-optimization games, code for clarity first, let the compiler do the tradeoffs between the costs of multiplications versus branch prediction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, your trick allows to avoid branch and it makes it faster... sometimes.

I wrote benchmark that compares these solutions in various situations, along with my own:

```
ticks += mStepSize & -static_cast<int>(running)
```

My results are following:

```
Off:
 branch: 399949150
 mul:    399940271
 andneg: 277546678
On:
 branch: 204035423
 mul:    399937142
 andneg: 277581853
Pattern:
 branch: 327724860
 mul:    400010363
 andneg: 277551446
Random:
 branch: 915235440
 mul:    399916440
 andneg: 277537411
```

`Off` is when timers are turned off. In this cases solutions take about the same time.

`On` is when they are turned on. Branching solution two times faster.

`Pattern` is when they are in 100110 pattern. Performance is similar, but branching is a bit faster.

`Random` is when branch is unpredictable. In this case multiplications is more than 2 times faster.

In all cases my bit-hacking trick is fastest, except for `On` where branching wins.

Note that this benchmark is not necessarily representative for all compiler versions processors etc. Even small changes of benchmark can turn results upside down (for example if compiler can inline knowing `mStepSize` is `1` than multiplication can be actually fastest).

Code of the benchmark:

```
#include<array>
#include<iostream>
#include<chrono>

struct Timer {
    bool running{false};
    int ticks{0};

    void branch(int mStepSize) {
        if(running) ticks += mStepSize;
    }

    void mul(int mStepSize) {
        ticks += mStepSize * static_cast<int>(running);
    }

    void andneg(int mStepSize) {
        ticks += mStepSize & -static_cast<int>(running);
    }
};

void run(std::array<Timer, 256>& timers, int step) {
    auto start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    for(int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
        for(auto& t : timers)
            t.branch(step);
    auto end = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    std::cout << "branch: " << (end - start).count() << std::endl;
    start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    for(int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
        for(auto& t : timers)
            t.mul(step);
    end = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    std::cout << "mul:    " << (end - start).count() << std::endl;
    start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    for(int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
        for(auto& t : timers)
            t.andneg(step);
    end = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    std::cout << "andneg: " << (end - start).count() << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    std::array<Timer, 256> timers;
    int step = rand() % 256;

    run(timers, step); // warm up
    std::cout << "Off:\n";
    run(timers, step);
    for(auto& t : timers)
        t.running = true;
    std::cout << "On:\n";
    run(timers, step);
    std::array<bool, 6> pattern = {1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0};
    for(int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
        timers[i].running = pattern[i % 6];
    std::cout << "Pattern:\n";
    run(timers, step);
    for(auto& t : timers)
        t.running = rand()&1;
    std::cout << "Random:\n";
    run(timers, step);
    for(auto& t : timers)
        std::cout << t.ticks << ' ';
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the tests! The results are very interesting, but surprising nonetheless. Seems the *best* way is `andneg` - I'm very surprised that the compiler does not apply that optimization. I'm also surprised by the fact that the branch can be faster than the multiplication. Guess there's actually no *best general* guideline to follow?

Comment: @VittorioRomeo, I think *best general* guideline is to wait with micro-optimizations until you have working program, to test what works best for your application and not to rely too much on micro-benchmarks.

Comment: `andneg` could actually be optimized even more to just `and`, if instead of keeping in `running` values `false`/`true` you would keep `int`s `0`/`-1`.

Comment: It really needs mentioned that the "bit-hacking trick" depends on implementation-defined 2's-complement representation of signed integers, which is not required to be how they are represented on all platforms, so this in theory makes for non-portable code, which could break in bizarre ways if ported to a less conventional platform (if such a thing exists anymore, and if they never get around to requiring 2c representation in the Standard).

Answer (score 2):

`Does the second version avoid a branch`

if you compile your code to get assembler output, `g++ -o test.s test.cpp -S`, you'll find that a branch is indeed avoided in the second function.

`and consequently, is faster than the first version`

i ran each of your functions `2147483647` or `INT_MAX` number of times where in each iteration i randomly assigned a boolean value to `running` member of your `Timer` struct, using this code:

```
int main() {
    const int max = std::numeric_limits<int>::max();
    timestamp_t start, end, one, two;
    Timer t_one, t_two;
    double percent;

    srand(time(NULL));

    start = get_timestamp();
    for(int i = 0; i < max; ++i) {
        t_one.running = rand() % 2;
        t_one.step_versionOne(1);
    }
    end = get_timestamp();
    one = end - start;

    std::cout << "step_versionOne      = " << one << std::endl;

    start = get_timestamp();
    for(int i = 0; i < max; ++i) {
        t_two.running = rand() % 2;
        t_two.step_versionTwo(1);
    }
    end = get_timestamp();
    two = end - start;

    percent = (one - two) / static_cast<double>(one) * 100.0;

    std::cout << "step_versionTwo      = " << two << std::endl;
    std::cout << "step_one - step_two  = " << one - two << std::endl;
    std::cout << "one fast than two by = " << percent << std::endl;
 }
```

and these are the results i got:

```
step_versionOne      = 39738380
step_versionTwo      = 26047337
step_one - step_two  = 13691043
one fast than two by = 34.4529%
```

so yes, the second function is clearly faster, and by around 35%. note that the percentage increase in timed performance varied between 30 and 55 percent for a smaller number of iterations, whereas it seems to plateau at around 35% the longer it runs. this is might be due to sporadic execution of system tasks while the simulation is running, which become a lot less sporadic, i.e. consistent the longer you run the sim (although this is just my assumption, i have no idea if it's actually true)

all in all, nice question, i learned something today!

---

### MORE:

---

of course, by randomly generating `running`, we are essentially rendering branch prediction useless in the first function, so the results above are not too surprising. however, if we decide to not alter `running` during loop iterations and instead leave it at its default value, in this case `false`, branch prediction will do its magic in the first function, and will actually be faster by almost 20% as these results suggest:

```
step_versionOne      = 6273942
step_versionTwo      = 7809508
step_two - step_one  = 1535566
two fast than one by = 19.6628
```

because `running` is constant throughout execution, notice that the simulation time is much shorter than it was with a randomly changing `running` - result of a compiler optimization likely.

why is the second function slower in this case? well, branch prediction will quickly realize that the condition in the first function is never met, and so will stop checking in the first place (as though `if(running) ticks += mStepSize;` isn't even there). on the other hand, the second function will still have to perform this instruction `ticks += mStepSize * static_cast<int>(running);` in every iteration, thus making the first function more efficient.

but what if we set `running` to `true`? well, the branch prediction will kick in again, however, this time, the first function will have to evaluate `ticks += mStepSize;` in every iteration; here the results when `running{true}`:

```
step_versionOne      = 7522095
step_versionTwo      = 7891948
step_two - step_one  = 369853
two fast than one by = 4.68646
```

notice that `step_versionTwo` takes a consistent amount of time whether `running` is constantly `true` or `false`. but it still takes longer than `step_versionTwo`, however marginally. well, this might be because i was too lazy to run it a lot of times to determine whether it's consistently faster or whether it was a one time fluke (results vary slightly every time you run it, since the OS has to run in the background and it's not always going to do the same thing). but if it is consistently faster, it might be because function two (`ticks += mStepSize * static_cast<int>(running);`) has an arithmetic op more than function one (`ticks += mStepSize;`).

finally, let's compile with an optimization - `g++ -o test test.cpp -std=c++11 -O1` and let's revert `running` back to `false` and then check the results:

```
step_versionOne      = 704973
step_versionTwo      = 695052
```

more or less the same. the compiler will do its optimization pass, and realize `running` is always `false` and will thus, for all intents and purposes, remove the body of `step_versionOne`, so when you call it from the loop in `main`, it'll just call the function and return.

on the other hand, when optimizing the second function, it will realize that `ticks += mStepSize * static_cast<int>(running);` will always generate the same result, i.e. `0`, so it won't bother executing that either.

all in all, if i'm correct (and if not, please correct me, i'm pretty new to this), all you'll get when calling both functions from the `main` loop is their overhead.

p.s. here's the result for the first case (`running` is randomly generated in every iteration) when compiled with an optimization.

```
step_versionOne      = 18868782
step_versionTwo      = 18812315
step_two - step_one  = 56467
one fast than two by = 0.299261
```

Comment: Thanks for the tests! However, this assumes that `running` constantly changes during execution. I wonder if the results are different when `running` has the same value 90% of the time?

Comment: I have a bit of trouble with this benchmark. 1. You compiled without optimizations. 2. You are not doing anything with results, so computation could be just optimized out. 3. I can't compile it - I don't know what `get_timestamp` is. 4. Compiler can inline with `mStepSize=1` and effectively remove multiplication leaving `ticks += static_cast<int>(running);`. 5. You are using `rand()` within benchmarked snippet which might be relatively costly. (I wrote this comment without seeing update, I don't know how much of it still applies)

Comment: @zch `get_timestamp` is a UNIX timestamp using `gettimeofday` that i have in a header file i used recently. i realize i'm not doing anything with the result and your point is valid. as far as `rand()` goes, don't know a better way to randomly change `running`. i did later on compile with `-O1` (`-O2` and `-O3` gave me `0`s everywhere?), and the results are pretty much identical whether `running` is constant, or randomly changing.

Comment: That's the point. You got zeros, because you are not using result. You need to print it or write to `volatile` or something like that to get meaningful results.