# Conditional Incrementing, Should you branch?

Tags: c++, c, performance

In regards to code performance, I'm curious in this situation since it has come up time and time again.

```
int val; //can be 0 or 1
if (val)
  global_var += val
```

OR:

```
int val; //can be 0 or 1
global_var += val
```

Basically, what's more expensive in terms of performance, branch mispredictions or unnecessarily incrementing by 0? Is there a general rule here, or does it relate case by case?

Comment: The correct answer is "it doesn't matter". But if you're curious for purely academic reasons, it would depend on the nature of the data. If `val` is most often 0, the branch prediction case will probably win. If it changes often, incrementing is probably better.

Comment: Is this in a critical section of code with hard deadlines?

Comment: @self. Its more of a curiosity. Also, when you try to increment by 0 does gcc or the processor still try to follow through with a such a command?

Comment: I swear I've already seen this question before.

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20163883/493122), sounds close enough.

Comment: How is your val set? It doesn't seem like it is a predetermined constant it does not seem that gcc can optimize it to avoid incrementing by 0 during compile time...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One cannot speak meaningfully about the performance of C code (or code in nearly any other language, for that matter).  One can perhaps talk meaningfully about performance of code compiled with one specific version of one compiler, at a specific optimization level targeting a specific architecture and executed on a specific implementation of that architecture, but even then you're leaving many things to chance (I've seen, for instance, someone's carefully hand-tuned code suffer a 50% performance regression when the name of the executable was changed).

That aside, on *most* modern architectures, comparison, conditional branch, and addition instructions are all single-cycle operations (and there are often execution port restrictions on branches).  On such architectures (which are all you are likely to encounter unless you are targeting something quite exotic), a single addition will always be at least as fast as the conditional addition, baring very unusual performance artifacts.

Branch misprediction cost doesn't enter into it at all.  By the time you do a conditional branch (even ignoring misprediction cost), you could have simply done the addition.

There are a few corner cases in this quick-and-dirty analysis: for example, if `global_var` is being used by many worker threads in the same fashion, and on nearly all of them `val` is zero, one could construct examples where using a conditional increment really is faster because it alleviates most of the contention for the cacheline on which `global_var` resides.  Alternatively, `global_var` could actually be a memory-mapped means of accessing some exotic hardware with extremely slow reads or writes; again, if `val` is usually zero, doing the increment conditionally might be a win.  All of these exceptions, however, are fairly specialized cases that most programmers will not encounter (and those who do encounter them hopefully know enough about what they’re doing to do this analysis themselves).  Note also that in all of these corner cases, the cost of branch prediction isn’t at issue; instead it’s the cost of accessing `global_var` that adds interest to the question.

Comment: The compiler cannot compile both snippets into the same code; doing so would be a violation of the memory model. In the first case, `global_var` is not accessed unless `val` is nonzero; inserting a gratuitous access could introduce data races. Thus, the latter case gives the compiler more freedom to optimize.

Comment: @R..: fair point.  (Of course, if the compiler can prove that the as-if rule applies ...)

Answer (score 1):

the code for either of these is so fast that it isn't going to matter in practicality...

someone could guess as to your architecture and how fast it is to pull which value out of which storage type and the likelihood of it being in a cache, if that is available in your architecture...

they both have pro's and cons... but in general avoiding a branch in preferable.

avoiding a branch is preferable not only because jumps are slower in many architectures... but because they allow for the compiler to perform more optimizations, and reduces complexity...

lesser complexity is good.

bugs live in complexity.